# subsetting dataframe in user defined function return 0 observations

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe all_order which has a lot of columns: ORDER_NUMBER, DATE, table, chair, book,etc. Each of the columns table, chair, book, etc. will have value of either 1 or 0.

I want to create a user defined function which will subset all_order by keeping only order_number, date and one of the other variables(table or chair or book or etc.) and only observations where table or chair or book is equal to 1. So far I have done like this

```
myfunc <- function(varia, newdate){


  new_file <- all_order[,c("ORDER_NUMBER","DATE",varia)]
  new_file <- subset(new_file,varia==1)
  new_file$newdate <- new_file$DATE
  myoutput <- new_file
  return(myoutput)

}

myoutput <- myfunc("table",table_date)
```

It always returns myoutput with 0 observation although I know it should not be. I have changed the second line of code as below but it still returns 0 observation.

```
new_file <- subset(new_file,as.name(varia)==1)
```

Can you someone please help me? Thanks.

Sample data is below:

```
ORDER_NUMBER                DATE table chair
1         15880107 2015-12-22 09:44:33     0     0
2         15880107 2016-03-15 14:35:12     0     0
3         15880107 2016-03-30 15:56:34     0     0
4         15880107 2016-03-24 15:02:11     0     0
5         35141357 2016-06-03 15:04:18     0     0
6         15880107 2015-10-14 14:39:04     0     0
7         15880107 2015-09-24 10:19:07     0     0
```

Comment: You can check the `str(all_order)` .  also, do you have 'table' column with 1 value in the data.  The line `new_file$newdate`  could be `new_file[newdate]`

Comment: yes. there are 10 observations with 1 value

Comment: What is `table_date`.  Is that a character string or value?  If it is a character string, then this will work `myfunc <- function(varia, newdate){


  new_file <- all_order[,c("ORDER_NUMBER","DATE",varia)];
  new_file <- new_file[new_file[[varia]]==1, , drop=FALSE];
  new_file[,newdate] <- new_file$DATE;
  myoutput <- new_file;
  myoutput
}`

Comment: table_date is date and time of the order (equal to column DATE). After the second line of code (new_file <- new_file[new_file[[varia]]==1, , drop=FALSE]; ), it still keeps all the 0 value

Comment: I think that is one problem.  YOu should be assigning a new column name on the lhs of `<-` for example if your `table_date <- "New"`, then the above would work.  Otherwise, if you are updating the 'DATE' column with 'table_date' as say `table_date <- "2015-01-01"`, then it should be `new_file$DATE <- table_date`

Comment: new_file[,newdate] <- new_file$DATE does work. Thank you. The only problem is after the 2nd line of code (new_file <- new_file[new_file[[varia]]==1, , drop=FALSE];), all 0 values are still kept

Comment: You should provide a complete reproducible example and update in your post.  According to my example, it is working fine.  I replaced the 2nd line of subset with `[` as it was a problem earlier.

Comment: I have added the sample data.

Comment: In your example, the 'table' are all 0, so it should give only 0 rows, but if I change the 5th elemnt to 1 and `table_new <- "new"; all_order$table[5] <- 1` then  `myfunc("table", table_date)#
  ORDER_NUMBER                DATE table                 new
5     35141357 2016-06-03 15:04:18     1 2016-06-03 15:04:18`

Comment: Hi akrun, sorry for this late reply. I have just been back from holiday.it works well now. Thank you